# Load csv file into MySQL for column with varchar but still loaded as numeric data type

Tags: mysql, csv

I tried to load a CSV file for postal codes, which should be stored as VARCHAR(10) in MySQL. The table was defined as follows:

```
Create TABLE PostalCode (postal_code VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL);
```

The loading was written as following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/postal_code.csv' 
INTO TABLE PostalCode
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@postal_code)
postal_code = CAST(@postal_code AS CHAR(10));
```

Say there is a postal_code 1000. Now calling sql `SELECT * FROM PostalCode WHERE postal_code = '1000'` gives an empty results. Meanwhile, `SELECT * FROM PostalCode WHERE postal_code = 1000` does give the row, which is NOT what I expect. This implies that the `posta_code` column is read as a numeric column...

Note that `DESCRIBE PostalCode` does show that the `postal_code` column is a VARCHAR(10).

Does anyone know the root cause and/or a solution?

p.s. The problem persists if I do not use cast in the loading code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/postal_code.csv' 
INTO TABLE PostalCode
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(postal_code);
```

**UPDATE:**

It may not be the case that the value is stored as numeric. It may still store as VARCHAR(10) because `SELECT * FROM PostalCode WHERE postal_code LIKE '1000%'` still gives me the wanted row. But why there is trailing characters? It seems that the trailing characters is not even space because using `TRIM` function does not help..

Comment: *But why there is trailing characters?* Look at `SELECT HEX(postal_code) FROM PostalCode;` - and you'll see the issue source.

Comment: While using data preprocessing the value is loaded into the variable as TEXT. So CAST to CHAR 
(and, in your particular case, the preprocessing at all) makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is resolved. It turns out that each line in that csv file is terminated using '\r' instead of '\n'. So it will be fixed by changing the sql to

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/postal_code.csv' 
INTO TABLE PostalCode
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@postal_code)
postal_code = CAST(@postal_code AS CHAR(10));
```

Lesson: be careful about your csv line termination character, especially when the csv comes from external sources